# Call functions in bluebird's then

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

How can I call a function inside of a then()? I am new to Bluebird and previously I would simply trigger the callback to inform that the called function is done with it's stuff.

Here is my "main code" which inserts locale data into my Mongo and Redis database.

```
var promise = Language.findOne({}).exec()

promise.then(function(languages) {
    /* If collection is empty initialize it */
    if(!languages)
        return insertLanguagesIntoMongoDB()
})
.then(function() {
    /* Make sure it's cached in Redis */
    return insertLanguagesIntoRedis()
})
.catch(function(err) {
    throw err
})
```

This is how my function looks like, but it says "callback is not a function":

```
function insertLanguagesIntoRedis(callback) {
    logger.info("Inserting languages into redis db")
    var promise = Language.find({}).exec()
    promise.then(function(languages) {
        if(!languages)
            throw new Error("Couldn't find any languages in MongoDB's Language collection")

        var languageJson = []
        for(var i=0; i<languages.length; i++) {
            var object = {}
            object.id = languages[i].iso_code
            object.text = languages[i].name_en
            languageJson.push(object)
        }
        redis.set('languages', JSON.stringify(languageJson))
        return callback()
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        throw err
    })
}
```

So how would I properly define and call my `insertLanguagesIntoRedis` and `insertLanguagesIntoMongoDB` functions?

Comment: Well you are not passing anything into insertLanguagesIntoRedis when you enter it.

Comment: @akaphenom Unfortunately I am very new to callbacks / bluebird, could you show me how to do that the proper way using bluebird?

Comment: In this case I don't think you need to pass in and even call a callback.  But I think you should look into how promises work and how to chain them together.

Comment: Why isn't that necessary? I thought I need to return something that I'm done with inserting, so that bluebird  knows it can continue with the next then() no?

Comment: how promises work is generally beyond  he scope of stack.  Start with Mozilla and read more from there.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines might work:

1. pass the languages into the promise chain
2. at the end of the chain return the promises into the next step
3. adjust the next step to accept the languages
4. adjust the insertLanguagesIntoRedis to accept the languages
5. have insertLanguagesIntoRedis return the promise chain
6. remove the callback invocation from insertLanguagesIntoRedis

var promise = Language.findOne({}).exec()

```
promise.then(function(languages) {
    /* If collection is empty initialize it */
    if(!languages)
        insertLanguagesIntoMongoDB()
     return languages
})
.then(function(languages) {
    /* Make sure it's cached in Redis */
    return insertLanguagesIntoRedis(languages)
})
.catch(function(err) {
    throw err
})

function insertLanguagesIntoRedis(languages) {
    logger.info("Inserting languages into redis db")
    var promise = Language.find({}).exec()
    return promise.then(function(languages) {
        if(!languages)
            throw new Error("Couldn't find any languages in MongoDB's Language collection")

        var languageJson = []
        for(var i=0; i<languages.length; i++) {
            var object = {}
            object.id = languages[i].iso_code
            object.text = languages[i].name_en
            languageJson.push(object)
        }
        redis.set('languages', JSON.stringify(languageJson))
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        throw err
    })
}
```

---

update per @Bergi

```
var promise = Language.findOne({}).exec()

promise.then(function(languages) {
    /* If collection is empty initialize it */
    if(!languages)
        insertLanguagesIntoMongoDB()
     return languages
})
.then(function(languages) {
    /* Make sure it's cached in Redis */
    return insertLanguagesIntoRedis(languages)
});

function insertLanguagesIntoRedis(languages) {
    logger.info("Inserting languages into redis db")
    var promise = Language.find({}).exec()
    return promise.then(function(languages) {
        if(!languages)
            throw new Error("Couldn't find any languages in MongoDB's Language collection")

        var languageJson = []
        for(var i=0; i<languages.length; i++) {
            var object = {}
            object.id = languages[i].iso_code
            object.text = languages[i].name_en
            languageJson.push(object)
        }
        redis.set('languages', JSON.stringify(languageJson))
    })
}
```

Comment: You can also drop the useless `.catch(function(err) { throw err })`